# Awk no longer supported on android, need replacement

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk

I got some old shell scripts which use awk to replace some tags in a file called awkLog to make it more readable. The current command looks something like this:

```
awk log.txt -f awkLog > output.txt
```

The purpose is that the script is going to write data in log.txt like cpu usage and so on and after that it would "parse" the data and write it to output.txt in the order as specified in awkLog.

I looked for some replacements but unfortnaly I have no experience with shell scripting... I found that some are using the command cut. But I can't see how to implement this in the shell scripts.

The code of awkLog:

```
BEGIN { maxfree = 0
        minfree = 10000000000 } 
    { savailable += $1 
      sused += $2
      sfree += $3
      sshared += $4
      sbuff += $5
      if ( $3 > maxfree ) maxfree = $3
      if ( $3 < minfree ) minfree = $3 }
END { print "MEMORY"
      mavailable = savailable/NR
      print "(average) available   : ", mavailable
      print "average used : ", sused/NR
      print "average free   : ", sfree/NR
      print "average shared   : ", sshared/NR
      print "average buff : ", sbuff/NR
      print "free max       : ", maxfree
      print "free min       : ", minfree
      print "Minimum MEMORY usage : ", mavailable-maxfree, "K"
      print "Maximum MEMORY usage : ", mavailable-minfree, "K"
      print "Average MEMORY usage : ", mavailable-sfree/NR, "K" }
```

Inside the log.txt it looks like this:

```
User 1%, System 3%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%
User 6 + Nice 0 + Sys 14 + Idle 420 + IOW 0 + IRQ 0 + SIRQ 0 = 440

  PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
10488  3   2% R     1   3704K   1248K  fg shell    top
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to offer concrete advice without seeing what `awkLog` does. Yes, maybe `cut` will be helpful, maybe rewrite to Perl or any other scripting language of choice.

Comment: Awk is still supported.

Comment: `awk` is still very much supported (as in "it's not deprecated"). If you need to replace `awk` with something else, you would have to investigate what the current script (`awkLog`) is doing and re-implement that in some other language or using some other parser. You mentioned "tags", does this mean that the current script is modifying XML?  Without seeing what the `awk` script is doing, nobody can tell you what to replace it with.

Comment: Ok maybe to make things bit more clear I'm talking about the shell in an android phone. Maybe there it is no longer supported? Also the awkLog contains variables like $1, $2, ... and so on.

Comment: Hi all I made the question a bit more clear as it was needed.

Answer (score 1):

what I understood from your question is that you would like to replace a string in a file. if it so, `sed` is the better command.

sed -i 's/oldString/newString/g' log.txt

Comment: The word "tag" implies XML (possibly), in which case the proper "replacement for `awk`" would be a an XML parser.